# Problem in deriving the Volume of an $n$-ball

Tags: calculus, integration, recurrence-relations, volume

I was trying to derive the Volume of an $n$-ball. With pure intuition, I could get to the following recurrence relation:
$$
V_{n + 1}\left(r\right)=\int_{-r}^{r}
V_{n}\left(\,\sqrt{\,{r^{2} - x^{2}}}\,\right){\rm d}x
$$
The function $V_{n}\left(r\right)$ gives the volume of the ball in the $n$th dimension given a radius $r$.

- If you cut a $3$d sphere into infinitely thin slices and add up the combined area of all those slices then it gives you the volume of the sphere.
- Here I just generalized that idea to the $n$th dimension.
- We can actually calculate the volume of any $n$-ball because we know the area of a circle which is $\pi r^{2}$ and with that, we can figure the volume of a sphere, hypersphere, and so on.

Here is where I got stuck I have no idea how to find an explicit formula:

- Is there any heuristic approach you can do to solve recurrent relations?
- The actual explicit formula when I searched it up involves the Gamma Function: How did Euler arrive at that formula? Is it by solving the recurrent relation?

Comment: This is a bit of a trick, but try expressing $V_n$ in terms of $V_{n-2}$, not $V_{n-1}$.

Comment: Also, as a simplifying assumption, you can assume $V_n(r)=C_nr^n$ for some sequence of constants $C_n$ - can you see why? (It would make more sense to call it $V_n$ but we're already using that name for a function and I don't want to use the same name for two different things)

Comment: As implied by the previous comment, $V_n(r) = [V_n(1)]r^n,$ so really all you need to find is $V_n(1).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The following  evaluation is a "direct" one. Namely, it starts from the volume $\ds{V_{n}}$ definition. Hereafter, $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$ is an *Iverson Bracket*.
\begin{align}
\left.\color{#44f}{\large V_{n}\pars{r}}\right\vert_{r\ >\ 0} & \equiv \color{#44f}{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{x_{1}^{2} + \cdots + x_{n}^{2} < r^{2}}\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}}
\\[1cm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\\[2mm] & 
\underbrace{\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\,\,
{\exp\pars{\pars{r^{2} - x_{1}^{2} - \cdots - x_{n}^{2}}s} \over s}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
_{\ds{\equiv \bracks{x_{1}^{2} + \cdots + x_{n}^{2} < r^{2}}}}
\\[2mm] & 
\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}
\\[1cm] & =
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\,\,
{\exp\pars{r^{2}\,s} \over s}
\pars{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-sx^{2}}\dd x}^{n}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} \\[5mm] & =
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\,\,
{\exp\pars{r^{2}\,s} \over s}
\pars{\root{\pi} \over s^{1/2}}^{n}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & = \pi^{n/2}\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\,\,
{\exp\pars{r^{2}\,s} \over s^{1 + n/2}}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & \sr{r^{2}\,s\ \mapsto\ s}{=}
\pi^{n/2}\,r^{n}\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\,\,
{\expo{s} \over s^{1 + n/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}
I'll deform the integration path such that the integral runs along a
[Hankel Contour](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.F1) $\ds{\cal H}$. The factor
$\ds{\left.\expo{s}\right\vert_{\Re\pars{s}\ <\ 0}}\,\,\,$ enforces the vanishing out of the integration along two quarter circle in $\ds{\braces{s \mid \Re\pars{s} < 0}}$. Namely,
$$
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\,\,
{\expo{s} \over s^{1 + n/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\cal H}\,\,
{\expo{s} \over s^{1 + n/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} = {1 \over \Gamma\pars{1 + n/2}}
$$
See the [Gamma Function Integral representation "along $\ds{\cal H}$"](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E2)

Therefore,
$$
\color{#44f}{\large V_{n}\pars{r}} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{\pi^{n/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + n/2}}\,r^{n}}}
$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The *Tradidional Derivation* is given by
\begin{align}
& \pi^{n/2} =
\pars{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x}^{n} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-x_{1}^{2} - \cdots - x_{n}^{2}}\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{0}^{\infty}C_{n}\expo{-R^{2}}\,R^{n - 1}\,\,\dd R =
C_{n}\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{n \over 2}} \implies
\bbx{C_{n} = {2\pi^{n/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n/2}}}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Therefore,}
\\ &\color{#44f}{\large V_{n}} = \int_{0}^{r}C_{n}\, R^{n - 1}\,\,\dd R = 
{2\pi^{n/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n/2}}\,{r^{n} \over n} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{\pi^{n/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + n/2}}\,r^{n}}} \\ & 
\end{align}
$\ds{\underline{A\ few\ examples:}}$
[image]